# Response.Headers.Remove("Server") does not work in global.Asax. see "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode" issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8, response-headers

I try to remove IIS 8.0 from server.
I use below code in Global.Asax.

```cs
   protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
        this.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
         Response.AddHeader("Server", "My httpd server");
    }
```

and
i use  below code in web.config

```
[httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000" requestValidationMode="2.0"  enableVersionHeader="false"]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4tY6.png)

when i try run the project  i see below issue

> "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode"

Although Manage Pipeline mode is integrated mode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ory7s.png)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code  / configuration.  Some users wont see them, and the text isn't searchable

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66796904/response-headers-removeserver-does-not-work-in-global-asax-see-this-operat